# Access options in MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access

How can I disable the access-options or to hide it?

### Update

If you open your MS Access 2007, you usually see the button at the upper left the "Microsoft Office button" and if you click on that, you'll see the different functions like: "new", "save", "open" etc and at the button you'll see the "access options" and "exit".

Comment: What do you mean by access-options?

Comment: hi again if you open your ms access 2007, you usually see the button at the upper left - "the microsoft office button" and if you click on that, you'll see the different functions like: "new", "save", "open" etc and at the button you'll see the "access options" and "exit"

Comment: For the current user or for the current database?

Comment: @Andreas Hoffmann: i'm not sure what do you mean with the current user and current database?could you please elaborate it further? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Make a ACCDE copy of the DB**
This will Strip out your VB source (but will leave the compiled code intact).
**but first get your menu setting the way you want**
e.g.
 1. click Access Options->Current Database.
 2. Uncheck  "Enable Full Menus" for this database
 3. From the Database Tools menu, choose "Make ACCDE"

**Note Unless you apply a valid digital signature to you DB, Access will warn about VB script and prompt user to Open or cancel** good thing is it will quit if they don't accept run VB script but its better to create a digital signature for your DB

Hope this helps

Comment: @10bithacker: i've already tried this one but this only works one time. i do it and re-open my database and the access option is gone. but then, if I close it now and re-open, the access option will show up again. don't know why...

Comment: Really? that's not the behavior I get. Once it's unchecked it stays unchecked unless I open it with Shift key held down. I've tried opening it from within Access and from explorer in both cases it opens with no DB design tools visible and "Access Options" Disabled.
How are you opening the DB?

Comment: yes this is really strange. i'm using windows 7 by the way and windows office 2007 for microsoft access... any idea why it's happening?

Comment: Probably it was opening with VB disabled, therefore the Settings were not being invoked on start up and hence the menu reappeared. I've edited my submission to save the DB as a ACCDE file instead this should fix the problem. Note: the ACCDE file does not contain source code only comliled VB code.

Comment: @10ToedSloth: ok that means I have to save my DB as ACCDE instead of ACCDB? I'll try that. and let you know the result

Comment: Yes export the version you intend to distribute to your users as a ACCDE file. Obviously you have to keep the original ACCDB file which contains your VB source code ,etc.

Comment: @10ToedSloth: Does that mean I have to make a back-up for the ACCDB file  before I convert it to ACCDE? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably this is only for the users.    You can create a shortcut which the users use on their desktops which has the /runtime command line option.   The problem though is you then have to add the path and file name of the msaccess.exe file, ie "C:\Program Files....\msaccess.exe"

Using the free [Auto FE Updater](http://autofeupdater.com/) makes this entire process a lot easier as well as automatically updating the FE as you make updates available to the users.